# Convert user input of any data type to str in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

So I have some user input (in Python) which can be any data type (int, str, unicode, etc) which I need to cast to type str. The problem I'm encountering is that if all the input were either string or unicode then I could use `myVar.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')` on the input, but since the input could be an int this doesn't work because ints don't have an encode function.

I've used `str(unicode(myVar, errors='ignore'))` and it has worked on my local machine, but my production environment throws the error: `"TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported"`, so I need to use another method. The double cast solution seems wrong in the first place.

Why is string encoding always such a mess? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not `str(myVar).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')`?

Comment: I do not understand the `int` part - if you use `raw_input` (Python 2) or `input` (Python 3) then what you get is an `str`, no need to cast

Comment: The question is then whether "input" refers to the `input()` function or to anything given at runtime (e.g. result from a user-defined function).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the .encode causes "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @WoJ I'm not getting the input from the console, it's actually from a dictionary of python objects.

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio: you could consider encoding it into JSON, if the data types in the input are compatible.

Comment: Maybe put the `.encode()` in a `try` block for `str` and Unicode data, and have the `except` block try again after casting `myVar` as an `int`?

Comment: @WoJ: seems a little heavy-handed

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's not pretty but I'm sure that would work. I might do that for now, but also wait for a better solution.

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio 'the .encode causes "UnicodeDecodeError: ..."' → I'm not sure I believe you. How does `encode` cause a `DecodeError`?

Comment: @Veedrac running these lines:
test_string = '\xe2abc'
test_string2 = str(test_string)
test_string3 = test_string2.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')

fails at the last line with "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)" (copy and pasted exactly)

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio Ah, I somehow failed to notice you are using Python 2. Python 3 is so much nicer, especially with unicode. Doesn't just `str(myVar)` work, though?

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio: what do you exactly mean by "heavy-handed"? Code-wise this is `your_dict=json.load(json.dump(your_dict))`. This will take care of `int`vs. `str` and some unicode. If you mean performance-wise - best would be to time it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(myVar if hasattr(myVar, 'encode') else str(myVar)).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

If the variable has an `encode` attribute, it's probably a string or Unicode object, and we can `encode()` it directly. If it doesn't, then it's probably an `int`, and we'll convert it with `str()` before trying to `encode()` it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
if isinstance(value, unicode):
    decoded_value = value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
elif isinstance(value, str):
    decoded_value = value.decode('ascii', 'ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
else:
    decoded_value = str(value)
```

If the value was a unicode object, it would gracefully move to a str encoded in ascii. If the value was a str, I needed to first decode it to unicode so that I could ignore all none ascii characters when I reencoded it. All other types just cast to str with no problems.